# Laravel 5.1 can't assign array in sync() method

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-5

I am using sync(). I can assign manually array data in sync. But I can't assign from varible.My code is below

```
$user = Book::find(63);
    $user->book_name = $request->input('book_name');
    $author  = $request->input('author');
    $user->authors()->sync($author);
```

From value is `author=[1,2,3]`
Return value is [1,2,3].
But value is not inserted in sync().
how can I do that in laravel 5.1?

Comment: Wait, what? `$user = Book::find(63);` ? Are you sure you want to use `Book` model there? I think you wanted to use `User` instead

Comment: $user = Book::find(63) is my test version. It should be $user = Book::find($id)